# How do I strip all formatting out of this Word VBA output and use the "Normal" quickstyle?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using the following VBA macro to add page numbers after all bookmark hyperlinks in my document:

```
Sub InsertPageRefs()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim hLnk As Hyperlink, Rng As Range
For Each hLnk In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
  With hLnk
    If InStr(.SubAddress, "_Toc") = 0 And .Address = "" Then
      Set Rng = .Range
      With Rng
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        .InsertAfter Text:=" (See page #)"
        .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
      End With
      ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=Rng.Characters(InStr(Rng, "#")), Text:="PAGEREF " & .SubAddress
    End If
  End With
Next
Set Rng = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ScreenRefresh
MsgBox ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Count & " page numbers have been added.", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

However, it's having undesirable results.

1. The blue color of the hyperlinks is partially spilling over into the added text.
2. It's creating a bunch of crazy span tags when I save the resulting file to HTML. I don't want this because I am going to convert the HTML to .mobi for Kindle and all the span tags are going to create chaos in my .mobi.

How do I strip out all the formatting and insert the page numbers in the "Normal" word style?

Comment: Put another way, I want the inserted text to inherit the style of the paragraph it's being inserted into.

Comment: And NOT muck up the underlying markup code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the ***real*** answer for this would be to use [a good e-book editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28application%29) that will keep track of this for you.

That said, the problem is likely that you are working on the Hyperlink's range, so all you should have to do is duplicate it.  This allows the formatting of your range separate itself from whatever formatting is attached to the hyperlink. The other benefit of using a duplicate of a Hyperlink's range is that you can operate on the text of the range directly without destroying the link, which is also an easy way to preserve the target formatting:

```
Sub InsertPageRefs()

    Dim hLnk As Hyperlink
    Dim Rng As Range

    For Each hLnk In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
        If InStr(hLnk.SubAddress, "_Toc") = 0 And hLnk.Address = vbNullString Then
            Set Rng = hLnk.Range.Duplicate
            Rng.Start = Rng.End
            Rng.Text = " (See page #)"
            Rng.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
            ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=Rng.Characters(InStr(Rng, "#")), _
                                      Text:="PAGEREF " & hLnk.SubAddress
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Count & " page numbers have been added.", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

Note that I pulled out the With blocks to make this more readable.  Nested Withs make it a lot more difficult to tell at a glance what object you're operating on.